# Headers for some columns that are grouped together based on column title prefixes

Tags: powerbi

I have this data on Power BI

| Column A | C1_open_inventory | C1_close_inventory |  | C2_open_inventory | C2_close_inventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell | Cell |  | Cell |  | Cell | Cell |
| Cell | Cell |  | Cell |  | Cell | Cell |

I want to create headers based on prefixes. The end state should look like this:

|          |                   C1                   ||                   C2                   |
| Column A |  open_inventory   ||  close_inventory  ||  open_inventory   ||  close_inventory  |
| -------- | ----------------- || ----------------- || ----------------- || ----------------- |
|   Cell   |       Cell        ||       Cell        ||       Cell        ||       Cell        |
|   Cell   |       Cell        ||       Cell        ||       Cell        ||       Cell        |

I haven't really tried any approach yet. I saw this similar case online but it's no longer applicable to the current version of PBI I think.

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Multiple-headers-on-some-columns-based-on-column-title-prefix/td-p/2247262

The table didn't turn out too well. I'll just paste the pictures from the link that I attached. I want to turn this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lxlx.png)

Into this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/471Ib.png)

Comment: The table didn't turn out too well. I'll just paste the tables from the link that I pasted.